# How will my main java class know if there was any exceptions raised in any other java classes

Tags: java, shell, exception, jar, count

I have a shell script which calls a JAR file. If there is any exception raised in any of the JAVA classes , the JAR should return a non zero value to the shell script using System.exit(). I have  2 approaches to this. Please guide me which is the best :

1. Declare a global variable in the main class with initial value as zero. Increment it in all the catch blocks in all the JAVA classes. While completing, the main class will call System.exit(1) if the global variable is greater than zero.
2. Keep on throwing all the exceptions to the main class and in the catch block of the main class, call System.exit(1). This will require many changes.

Let me know if there is any Other way.

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 is best. You should never be using global variables, it is an indicator of bad design. Copy pasting the same bit of code to a bunch of different places is also bad design. Properly throwing and catching exceptions is always the right way to handle this.

Comment: Thanks @nhouser9 . What could be the harm in using a global variable?

Comment: @SatejKoli see this question for a short explanation: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil I am sure you could also find more if you wanted to search on the topic. Please don't forget to upvote and accept if this answer was helpful =]

Comment: Thanks @nhouser9 . The link you posted has explained everything in detail. However, as far as my program is considered , it seems harmless to use the global variable. What do you think specifically about my program?

Comment: Also, I observed that using 'throw ' can change the program flow. Hence, I have finally decided to create a separate class , declare a static variable there and also create a static function which will increment the variable value. Whenever, an exception is caught, this function will be called. In the end, the Main java class will call another static function of the new class to get the variable value.